# Import Scipy module in Blender

Tags: python, scipy, blender

I'm using Blender 2.76b using Ubuntu 15.10.

I'm tryng to use scipy module in Blender. I tried coping the scipy folder from "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy" to ".../.blender-2.76b-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.76/scripts/modules/scipy".

Then, if run:

```
import scipy
```

it works, but if I try with:

```
from scipy import interpolate
```

it returns the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/alessandro/Scrivania/untitled.blend/Text", line 6, in 
>     File "/home/alessandro/.blender-2.76b-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.76/scripts/modules/scipy/interpolate/**init**.py", line 160, in 
>       from .interpolate import *
>     File "/home/alessandro/.blender-2.76b-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.76/scripts/modules/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 15, in 
>       import scipy.special as spec
>     File "/home/alessandro/.blender-2.76b-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.76/scripts/modules/scipy/special/**init**.py", line 546, in 
>       from ._ufuncs import *
>   ImportError: No module named 'scipy.special._ufuncs'
>   Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

Looking at the content of "scipy/specials" and looking for a _ufuncs.py I only found those:

> .../scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>
> .../scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>
> .../scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>
> .../scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

For some reasons Blender cannot handle the files... someone can please suggest something to do?

Thank you in advice,
Alessandro

[EDIT]
I also tried with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/python3/dist-packages/')
import scipy
```

but Blender doesn't find scipy... :-(

Comment: I wrote a post regarding python imports from anaconda that might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164666/why-arent-python-packages-from-anaconda-being-detected-by-blender/35167361#35167361

Answer (score 0):

Looks like blender still uses Python 2 while you copied `scipy` from a Python 3 installation.
I would expect that installing the Python 2 scipy would make it available to blender without any copying action.

Comment: Hi Bluehorn, actually Blender have a built-in Python 3. Anyway I tried coping "Scipy" from Python 2.7 folder (I have installed it for both version of Python), and the result is a bit different:

Comment: .................
  File "/home/alessandro/.blender-2.76b-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.76/scripts/modules/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 546, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: /home/alessandro/.blender-2.76b-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.76/scripts/modules/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Comment: Sorry, I guess the path names in the error message refer to Blender 2.76, not Python 2.7.6. In general copying is a bad idea since it does not take care of dependencies...

Comment: From the error message it seems that Python actually tries to load those files, and they are actually for the wrong Python version now. I guess the previous attempt was more successful but failed because scipy dependencies were missing. The original error was most likely dropped on the way to the caller.